# User input from editText to a String

Tags: java, android

I looks like a simple question, but i can't manage to get it to work.

I'm trying to make weather app, and im using Yahoo API, And like this the app works:

```
        service.refreshWeather("Dallas, TX");
```

I wanted to make the user input the city, so i made this:

```
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mDugme);
    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unesiGrad);
    String userInput11;



    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                     userInput11 = mEdit.getText().toString();
                }
            });

    service.refreshWeather(userInput11);
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: move your code inside `onClick(..)`

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                     userInput11 = mEdit.getText().toString();
                }
            });

    service.refreshWeather(userInput11);
```

and reorder it to look like this

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                         userInput11 = mEdit.getText().toString();
                         service.refreshWeather(userInput11);
                    }
                });
```

It may demand to declare service as final. I am not sure. Just follow IDE instructions.

Comment: are you sure service will be available inside listener method?

Comment: Should, try and see what will happen :P

Comment: Thank you, its working. Do you mind to help me how to use shared preference on this (That's how i save the data, right?) i tried couple methods but i was unsuccessful(kinda new to whole android programming).

Comment: @Mr.Vit This is not a "show me how to do X and Y" service. SharedPreferences is really basic stuff and you can find about a 100 tutorials about it on the net

Comment: I can try if you describe your problem, say what you was trying and post some code.

Comment: @404notfound thanks for helping out! i tried and learned about sharedPrefs and [this is what i got](http://pastebin.com/gA343BXD), but it isnt good.